# Is there a way to have different Opacity props between parent and child usercontrols?

Tags: wpf, properties, parent-child, opacity

I have a scrollView.
There is an itemsControl in it.
So I want to set opacity 50% to scrollview, but want to have 100% opacity to itemsControl.

Now, if I set 50% opacity to SV, so I have 50% opacity to itemsControl too.

Is there a way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always overwrite the [ScrollViewer's Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970847.aspx) so only the `ScrollBar` parts are at 50% opacity

The simplified template looks like this:

```
<Grid>
  <Border>
    <ScrollContentPresenter />
  </Border>

  <!-- Set Opacity of these only -->
  <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" />
  <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" />
</Grid>
```